# NPM not installing the required dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, mean-stack

I cloned a repository, its a MEAN stack application, first thing I did was `npm install`. but in the end it said

```
added 1580 packages from 1887 contributors and audited 15249 packages in 281.586s
found 18 vulnerabilities (5 low, 12 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried `npm audit fix` and it said

```
up to date in 15.221s
fixed 0 of 18 vulnerabilities in 15249 scanned packages
  9 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
  4 package updates for 9 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)
```

here is the list of my installed packages

```
D:\Opticare\opticare>npm list -depth=0
opticare@0.0.0 D:\Opticare\opticare
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/animations@5.2.11
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.2.11
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@5.2.11
+-- @angular/http@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.11
+-- @angular/router@5.2.11
+-- @auth0/angular-jwt@2.1.2
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
+-- @swimlane/ngx-charts@7.4.0
+-- @types/datatables.net@1.10.18
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.16
+-- @types/jquery@3.3.31
+-- @types/node@6.0.118
+-- @types/systemjs@0.20.7
+-- angular-archwizard@3.0.0
+-- angular-datatables@6.0.1
+-- angular2-csv@0.2.9
+-- angular2-spinner@1.0.10
+-- bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3
+-- chalk@2.4.2
+-- chart.js@2.9.3
+-- codelyzer@4.5.0
+-- core-js@2.6.11
+-- cron@1.8.2
+-- datatables.net@1.10.20
+-- datatables.net-dt@1.10.20
+-- express@4.17.1
+-- file-saver@1.3.8
+-- googleapis@35.0.0
+-- http-errors@1.7.3
+-- jasmine-core@2.8.0
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- jodit-angular@1.0.86
+-- jquery@3.4.1
+-- jsonwebtoken@8.5.1
+-- jwt-decode@2.2.0
+-- karma@2.0.5
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- lodash@4.17.15
+-- moment@2.24.0
+-- moment-timezone@0.5.27
+-- mongoose@5.8.10
+-- mongoose-paginate@5.0.3
+-- multer@1.4.2
+-- ng2-nouislider@1.8.2
+-- ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5
+-- ngx-chips@1.9.8
+-- ngx-toastr@6.5.0
+-- node-cron@1.2.1
+-- node-sass@4.13.1
+-- nodemailer@4.7.0
+-- nouislider@11.1.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.5.12
+-- shortid@2.2.15
+-- ts-helpers@1.1.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@^5.0.0
+-- twilio@3.39.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.9.2
+-- xlsx@0.13.5
`-- zone.js@0.8.29

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/animations@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@>=6.0.0, required by @auth0/angular-jwt@2.1.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0, required by angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^6.1.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^6.0.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.7, required by @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11
npm ERR! peer dep missing: tslint@^5.0.0, required by codelyzer@4.5.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.0.0, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@3.3.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by angular-datatables@6.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^6.1.0, required by ngx-chips@1.9.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.8, required by tsickle@0.27.5
```

this is my `npm audit` report

```
D:\Opticare\opticare>npm audit

                       === npm audit security report ===

# Run  npm install --save-dev karma@4.4.1  to resolve 3 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

  Moderate        Memory Exposure

  Package         tunnel-agent

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > request > tunnel-agent

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/598




  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         braces

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > expand-braces > braces

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786




  Moderate        Denial of Service

  Package         axios

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > axios

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/880



# Run  npm install @angular/compiler-cli@8.2.14  to resolve 1 vulnerability
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         braces

  Dependency of   @angular/compiler-cli

  Path            @angular/compiler-cli > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch >
                  braces

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786



# Run  npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@8.3.23  to resolve 4 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         braces

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > @angular-devkit/core > chokidar > anymatch >
                  micromatch > braces

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786




  Low             Denial of Service

  Package         mem

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > webpack > yargs > os-locale > mem

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1084




  Moderate        Cross-Site Scripting

  Package         serialize-javascript

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > copy-webpack-plugin > serialize-javascript

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426




  Moderate        Cross-Site Scripting

  Package         serialize-javascript

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin >
                  serialize-javascript

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426



# Run  npm install googleapis@47.0.0  to resolve 1 vulnerability
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

  High            Improper Authorization

  Package         googleapis

  Dependency of   googleapis

  Path            googleapis

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/791




                                 Manual Review
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance


  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         timespan

  Patched in      No patch available

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > timespan

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/533


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > less > request > hawk > boom > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > request > hawk > boom > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > less > request > hawk > cryptiles > boom >
                  hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > request > hawk > cryptiles > boom
                  > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > less > request > hawk > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > request > hawk > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   @angular/cli [dev]

  Path            @angular/cli > less > request > hawk > sntp > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   karma [dev]

  Path            karma > log4js > loggly > request > hawk > sntp > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566

found 18 vulnerabilities (5 low, 12 moderate, 1 high) in 15249 scanned packages
  9 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
  9 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

This is the 3rd time I'm cloning the repository from scratch to make it running.

and here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "opticare",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.4.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-spinner": "^1.0.10",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "googleapis": "^35.0.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.6.3",
    "jodit-angular": "^1.0.59",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.4",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.4.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.19.2",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.13.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/systemjs": "^0.20.5",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Now my question is:

why, when I explicitly install the package mentioned in front of `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`, it still stays the same, even after installation the required version ?

How do I run this application ? I'm extremely exhausted by trying different methods to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

run `ncu` for list or just run `ncu -u` to upgrade automatically.

If still It won't fix then in my project,

I used the command:
 `npm audit fix --force`

and after I run:

````
npm install
npm WARN assets No description

audited 7779 packages in 3.914s
found 0 vulnerabilities```
````

Comment: The second way fixed my issue and maybe it will help you also. If still not then let me know with the console warnings or errors.

Comment: `'ncu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Oh!! Then Did you try the second way ? @Ahsan

Comment: Sometimes, this is related to package-lock.json. I would suggest to try to:

1 - Delete your package-lock.json

2 - Delete your node_modules folder

3 - Try npm install again

This used to fix several issues when adding new packages in my angular apps.

Good luck!